# What's wrong with this exe package, dlls aren't merging?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, executable, ddl

I'm making runable package, and I want to use dlls.

In code I use relative path.

```
IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@"..\..\Assemblies\aesCPP.dll");
```

Everything works great when I'm running it from VS.

Here is how I wanted to make it in directory.:

[image]

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I have no idea why.

Comment: Please make sure that all the information required is within the question itself. Always try and indicate the runtime environment (i.e. the language) too to attract visitors to your question.

Comment: Is this somehow related or identical to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3836531/s3ven). Please indicate this as well in your question. If they are identical, delete one of them.

Comment: Of course, you are right